# R: Filter a Dataframe containing a list

Tags: r, dataframe, list, filter

I have a data frame like this one:

| Name | Parameter1 |
| --- | --- |
| Johny | c(11,4,35) |
| Michael | c(1,3,9) |

I want to filter the data frame for Parameter1 that has at least one value (in the vector) of more than 10

The result I am expecting is

| Name | Parameter1 |
| --- | --- |
| Johny | c(11,4,35) |

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: provide that data frame by running `dput(df)` over your data frame `df`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
> subset(df, sapply(Parameter1, max) > 10)
   Name Parameter1
1 Johny  11, 4, 35
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use the **dplyr::filter()** function, combined with the **any()** and **purrr::map_lgl()** functions. Here's a possible solution:

```
# Load the dplyr package
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# Create the example data frame
data <- data.frame(
 Name = c("Johny", "Michael"),
 Parameter1 = I(list(c(11, 4, 35), c(1, 3, 9)))
)

# Filter the data frame
filtered_data <- data %>%
 filter(map_lgl(Parameter1, ~ any(.x > 10)))
```

In this solution, I used the map_lgl() function from the purrr package to create a logical vector indicating whether any element in Parameter1 is greater than 10. The filter() function from the dplyr package is then used to filter the data frame based on this logical vector.

Comment: Base R equivalent `data[sapply(data$Parameter1, function(z) any(z > 10)),]`

Answer (score 1):

One way could be like this:

Here we use `tidyr::separate_rows` to bring all values in the list in one row.
then we use `readr::parse_number()` to check the condition and filter >10,
finally we us `toString` to get the desired output:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(Parameter1, sep = ",") %>% 
  filter(any(parse_number(Parameter1) >10), .by = Name) %>% 
  summarise(Parameter1 = toString(Parameter1), .by=Name)

 Name  Parameter1  
  <chr> <chr>       
1 Johny c(11, 4, 35)
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(Hour = 0:5, Giraffe = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L
), Elephant = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Lion = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```